# How to decode a binary payload from a sensor into a Json payload

Tags: c#, json, .net-core, decode, azure-iot-hub

I have this sensor:

https://cdn.antratek.nl/media/wysiwyg/pdf/RM_Sound_Level_Sensor_20200319_BQW_02_0011.pdf

And I am using Azure IoT Hub to stream messages from devices.

As this is a lorawan sensor I need to decode the payload with a custom decoder.

and I found this great document here:
https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-lorawan-starterkit/blob/9124bc46519eccd81a9f0faf0bc8873e410d31a6/Samples/DecoderSample/ReadMe.md

Where I have some piece of  code:

```
internal static class LoraDecoders
{
    private static string DecoderValueSensor(string devEUI, byte[] payload, byte fport)
    {
        // EITHER: Convert a payload containing a string back to string format for further processing
        var result = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(payload);

        // OR: Convert a payload containing binary data to HEX string for further processing
        var result_binary = ConversionHelper.ByteArrayToString(payload);

        // Write code that decodes the payload here.

        // Return a JSON string containing the decoded data
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { value = result });

    }
}
```

Now the question is based on the document above section 4.1.2

What should I do in .net after this line:

```
 var result_binary = ConversionHelper.ByteArrayToString(payload);
    
            // Write code that decodes the payload here.
```

Comment: I would use the string results.  Try adding Console.WriteLine(result);

Answer (score 2):

You could decode payload using [bitwise operators in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/bitwise-and-shift-operators).

For example, the 4-byte payload described in referenced document Section 4.1.2 could be converted into a C# struct:

```
enum SensorStatus
{
    KeepAlive = 0,
    TriggerThresholdEvent = 1
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct Payload
{
    // Section 4.1.2 Payload
    private byte _status;
    private byte _battery;
    private byte _temp;
    private byte _decibel;

    // Decode
    public SensorStatus SensorStatus => (SensorStatus)(_status & 1);

    public int BatteryLevel => (25 + (_battery & 15)) / 10;

    public int Temperature => (_temp & 127) - 32;

    public int DecibelValue => _decibel;

    public bool HasDecibelValue => DecibelValue != 255;
}
```

To create such [sequential struct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.structlayoutattribute?view=netcore-3.1) from a byte array of 4, you could use [`Unsafe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe?view=netcore-3.1) class:

```
var payloadBytes = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var payload = Unsafe.As<byte, Payload>(ref payloadBytes[0]);
```

You could then serialize your `payload` struct:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented);
```

It produces JSON:

```
{
  "SensorStatus": 1,
  "BatteryLevel": 2,
  "Temperature": -29,
  "DecibelValue": 4,
  "HasDecibelValue": true
}
```

Comment: thank you, I will try this as soon as possible and let you know if it works

Comment: where exactly do you put the result_binary parameter from my code here?

Comment: The `result_binary` is an example, which shows you could either convert the `byte[]` to HEX format and just return that in your JSON, then your client of the API will parse the hex string. OR, if the `byte[]` is essentially a utf8 encoded string, you could parse it back to string, and return the string in JSON. They are all examples. Same as mine. Mine is parsing the `byte[]` array directly from `byte[]` to JSON as per the specs, so `result` and `result_binary` no longer needed.